# Residual not Orthogonal to the span of selected atoms

Tags: matlab, statistics, sparse-matrix, approximation

I am trying to implement orthogonal Matching Pursuit algorithm. The algorithm can be found here.

https://in.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ug/matching-pursuit-algorithms.html

It says that the residual is orthogonal to span of selected atoms  but I am getting only the first selected atom as orthogonal to the residual. No later selected atoms are coming out to be orthogonal to the residual. Kindly check the code and explain where Am I doing it wrong?

```
clc,clear;

dictionary = [1 0; 1/2 sqrt(3)/2; -1/sqrt(2) -1/sqrt(2)]';

t=5;
s=[1;1/2];

r=s;
atoms=zeros(size(dictionary,1),size(dictionary,2));
coefs=zeros(size(dictionary,2),1);

%Normalize the dictionary 
for index=1:size(dictionary,2)
   dictionary(:,index)=dictionary(:,index)./norm(dictionary(:,index)); 
end
D=dictionary;

index=[];
while(t>1e-15 && sum(dictionary(:)~=0))%Process while (Eucledian norm > 10^-15)
    inner_product=dictionary'*r; %Dot Product
    [m,ind]=max(abs(inner_product));
    index=[index ind];
    atoms(:,ind)=dictionary(:,ind); %Select atom which has maximum inner product
    x=(atoms(:,ind)'*atoms(:,ind))\(atoms(:,ind)'*r);
    coefs(ind)=x;
    r=r-atoms(:,ind)*x;  

    t=power(norm(r),2);


end
```

More Links:
Contains Screen shots of the same algorithm from different papers:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!ArfYMunvE-HGgZoFHHPx7kdN5Am6Bg

https://1drv.ms/i/s!ArfYMunvE-HGgZoEBo6uh0xYGzl7Rg